# ESlint extension in VScode could not work on MacBook pro 2021 Apple M1 Pro

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I used the eslint in vscode on Apple M1 pro chips.

I can execute the eslint by command line well:

```
> eslint app.js


/playground/nodejs/eslint-demo/app.js
  1:7  error  'a' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

But the vscode eslint extension could not work:

I got the error message like:

```
[Info  - 2:09:20 PM] ESLint server is starting.
[Info  - 2:09:20 PM] ESLint server running in node v19.4.0
[Info  - 2:09:20 PM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 2:21:17 PM] ESLint library loaded from: /playground/nodejs/eslint-demo/node_modules/eslint/lib/unsupported-api.js
Uncaught exception received.
Error: Unexpected key "env" found.
    at ObjectSchema.validate (/playground/nodejs/eslint-demo/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/object-schema/src/object-schema.js:203:23)
    at /playground/nodejs/eslint-demo/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/object-schema/src/object-schema.js:171:18
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at ObjectSchema.merge (/playground/nodejs/eslint-demo/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/object-schema/src/object-schema.js:169:24)
    at /nodejs/eslint-demo/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/config-array/api.js:916:42
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at FlatConfigArray.getConfig (/playground/nodejs/eslint-demo/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/config-array/api.js:915:39)
    at FlatESLint.calculateConfigForFile (/playground/nodejs/eslint-demo/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/flat-eslint.js:1182:24)
    at async FlatESLint.isPathIgnored (/playground/nodejs/eslint-demo/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/flat-eslint.js:1204:24)
    at async /.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.4.0/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:23325
Uncaught exception received.
```

I add file `./.vscode/settings.json` in the project root directory

```json
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "./"
  ],
  "eslint.options": {
    "overrideConfigFile": "./.eslintrc.js"
  }
}
```

and the `eslintrc.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: "eslint:recommended",
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  rules: {},
};
```

vscode versions:

```
Version: 1.79.0 (Universal)
Commit: b380da4ef1ee00e224a15c1d4d9793e27c2b6302
Date: 2023-06-07T14:29:00.206Z
Electron: 22.5.5
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.3.0
```

eslint version:

```
❯ eslint -v                                                                                                                                              
v8.39.0
```

machine:

```
MacBook pro 2021 
Chip: Apple M1 Pro
macOS: Ventura 13.2.1
```

How could I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is old, but ESLint seems to be looking for the "Flat" one

Disable "Use Flat config" option in VSCode ESLINT settings
Well, or rewrite your config into a Flat one: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new

Don't use `overrideConfigFile` - if you don't use Flat it's inferred, and if you do use Flat config name is strict